# Are there any redundant divs in my first proper webpage? Or any way to group classes in my CSS file

Tags: html, css, html5

This is my first full formatted webpage done while doing the odin project.

Is there any redundant divs? Can I reduce my css file by grouping some classes?

And how to give styles to a button under a specific div without using class?

```css
html{
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.header{
    background-color: #1f2937;
    padding-top:10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo{
    color:#f9faf8;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
a{
    color:#e5e7eb;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:7px;
}
.hero{
    background-color: #1f2937;
    display:flex;
    padding:70px 90px 80px 90px;
    gap:20px;
}
.hero-image{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: gray;
    height:30vh;
    width: 45vw;
    color: #e5e7eb;
}
h2{
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#f9faf8;
    margin:0;
}
.random{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding:20px 20px 100px 20px;
}
.info{
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #1f2937;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.random-image{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: #3882f6;
    height:105px;
    width:105px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.quote{
    background-color:#e5e7eb;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 60px 250px 60px 250px;
}
.quote-text{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #1f2937;
}
p{
    color:#e5e7eb;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:0;
}
.action{
    background-color: #3882f6;
    margin: 80px 110px 80px 110px;
    padding: 50px 90px 50px 90px;
    color: #f9faf8;
    display: flex;
    gap:300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button{
    background-color:#3882f6;
    color:#f9faf8;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding:7px 25px 7px 25px;
}

.footer{
    background-color: #1f2937;
    color:#e5e7eb;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Odin-Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='header'>
        <div class='logo'>
            <u>ONE PIECE</u>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="">Manga</a>
            <a href="">Anime</a>
            <a style="padding-right:35px" href="">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='hero'>
        <div style="width:80vh"> 
            <h2>One Piece is really awesome </h2>
            <p>One Piece written by Eichiro Oda is the most popular manga in the world, surpassing the likes of Batman and other 
                multi-author comics.
            </p>
            <button style="border-width: 0;margin-top: 4px;">Sign up</button>
        </div>
        <div  class='hero-image'>

            <img src='one-piece.jpg' style="height:45vh;width: 45vw;">
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class='random'>
        <div class='info'>Some random information.</div>
        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;text-align: center;">
            <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
                <img class='random-image' src='luffy.png'>
                <div>The protaganist Monkey D.Luffy aka Rubber boy</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class='random-image' src='wings.png'>
                <div>The wings of the future Pirate King</div>
            </div> 
            <div>
                <img class='random-image' src='whitebeard.png'>
                <div>The strongest man in the world</div>
            </div> 
            <div style="padding-right:100px;">
                <img class='random-image' src='usopp.png'>
                <div>The only God in one piece universe</div>
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class='quote'>
        <div class='quote-text'>Pirates are evil? The Marines are righteous?… Justice will prevail, you say?
             But of course it will! Whoever wins this war becomes justice!</div>
        <div style="text-align:right;font-size: 25px;"><b>-Donquixote Doflamingo</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class='action'>
        <div>
            <b>Call to action! It's time!</b><br>
            Support one piece by clicking that button right over there!
        </div>
        <div>
            <button style="border-color: white;border-style: solid;">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        Copyright Gagan Karanth 2021
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any standard order in arranging the css classes among professionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And how to give styles to a button under a specific div without using class?

You can do this:

```
.action button {
    /* styles */
}
```

The selector selects all `button`s that’re decendants of elements that have the class `action`.

---

Your HTML contains many inline styles (`style="…"`); it’s generally best to avoid doing that.

for instance:

```
<div class='info'>Some random information.</div>
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;text-align: center;">
…
</div>
```

Consider using a class for the 4-column section instead of inline styles.

---

```
<div class='header'>
…
</div>
…
<div class='footer'>
    Copyright Gagan Karanth 2021
</div>
```

These divs can be replaced with HTML5 `<header>` and `<footer>` tags.

---

```
<div>
    <a href="">Manga</a>
    <a href="">Anime</a>
    <a style="padding-right:35px" href="">About</a>
</div>
…
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;text-align: center;">
    <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
        <img class='random-image' src='luffy.png'>
        <div>The protaganist Monkey D.Luffy aka Rubber boy</div>
    </div>
    …
    <div style="padding-right:100px;">
        <img class='random-image' src='usopp.png'>
        <div>The only God in one piece universe</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

`padding-left` and `padding-right` should usually be applied to parent elements rather than to the first children and to the last children.

I would change the navigation links’ (Manga, Anime, and About)’s container element from a `div` to a `nav`, then delete the inline style `padding-right:35px` from the "About" link and declare it in `nav`’s CSS.

```
<nav>
    <a href="">Manga</a>
    <a href="">Anime</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
</nav>

nav {
    padding-right: 35px;
}
```

Likewise to the 4-columns part (adding a class and moving the inline styles to the CSS per a previous suggestion):

```
<div class='images'>
    <div>
        <img class='random-image' src='luffy.png'>
        <div>The protaganist Monkey D.Luffy aka Rubber boy</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='random-image' src='wings.png'>
        <div>The wings of the future Pirate King</div>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <img class='random-image' src='whitebeard.png'>
        <div>The strongest man in the world</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='random-image' src='usopp.png'>
        <div>The only God in one piece universe</div>
    </div> 
</div>

.images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;

    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

---

Some colors in the CSS are repeated throughout the file. [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are useful for keeping all colors’ definitions in 1 place.

```
:root {
    --dark-bg: #1f2937;
}
…
.header, .hero {
    background-color: var(--dark-bg);
}
.info, .quote-text {
    color: var(--dark-bg);
}
```

But old browsers can’t do CSS custom properties, or variables.

Comment: I'm using codereview for the first time. Should I apply your suggestions and edit the question here in website? Or should I leave it as it is?